# How to get latest three posts from the same category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a new Website with WordPress and PHP. I'd need to get the latest three posts from the same category of the post I'm currently on. In addition, I need to avoid that the post I'm watching goes into the list of the three posts.

I tried the code below so at the moment I just can display the name of three posts even though they ae not of same category...

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>      
</h2>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I except the three latest posts to be of the same category of the website page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress posts from the same category below post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340509/wordpress-posts-from-the-same-category-below-post)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the category parameter in your code.

```
$category_id = 1;
$posts= new WP_Query(array(
    'cat'            => $category_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 3
));
```

Then access it using

```
<?php while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340509/wordpress-posts-from-the-same-category-below-post